# Trying to custome install mysql workbench and server using Mysql installer but the list under 'Available products' is completely empty for me?

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-workbench

Tried with versions 5.7.33.0, 5.7.20.0 and 8.0.23.0 but the result is the same. Using Windows 10 version 1909. Image attached, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try going back in the step list and see if you can select a predefine set of products.

Comment: Thanks for the input @MikeLischke, however selecting a predefined set products didn't work either. Recently I had changed a few system settings to optimize another application which caused the problem, fortunately I had created a system restore point, restoring it partially has solved the problem and I was able to install the latest version of Mysql workbench and server.